# On iOS, can you add multiple CIFilters to a SpriteKit node?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, core-image, cifilter, skeffectnode

On iOS, can you add more than one `CIFilter` to a `SKEffectsNode`?

[`CIFilterGenerator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cifiltergenerator?language=objc) seems like what I want but it isn't available on iOS.

I know you can use [multiple filters on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778259/multiple-cifilters-in-one-ciimage) by passing the output of one as the input of the next, but that's not helpful if you want to affect non-image nodes.

Does this mean I have to create an artificial hierarchy of `SKEffectNode` and add a filter to each of them, with my actual content at the very bottom? Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't use SpriteKit, but the documentation for SKEffectNode says you can apply a CIFilter to it. So I'd think if you can *only* apply a single filter, you should be able to (1) subclass CIFilter and (2) chain the filters you want, then (3) optionally set up attributes for dynamic changing of them. Next, you can (4) subclass CIFilterConstructor so that you can (5) register your new CIFilter and it should be used exactly like any other CIFilter. I could post some sample code if you think this is a good route to go.

Comment: Great suggestion. This approach worked. I'd like to post my code but I'd also like to give you credit for your answer. If you want to post this text as an answer I will add my code to it (which you can feel free to improve, if necessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where it's difficult or impossible to "chain" together multiple `CIFilter` calls to achieve the desired effect - maybe due to a class that has a single property, one way to overcome this is to do the following:

- Subclass `CIFilter`, overriding everything you need to. This may include `attributes`, `setValue(forKey:)`, and most importantly, `outputImage`.
- Subclass `CIFilterConstructor`, and create a `registerFilter()` method.

For example, let's say you wish to combine a gaussian blur and then add a monochrome red tone to an image. At it's most basic you can do this:

```
class BlurThenColor:CIFilter {

    let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")

    override public var attributes: [String : Any] {
        return [
            kCIAttributeFilterDisplayName: "Blur then Color",

            "inputImage": [kCIAttributeIdentity: 0,
                           kCIAttributeClass: "CIImage",
                           kCIAttributeDisplayName: "Image",
                           kCIAttributeType: kCIAttributeTypeImage]
        ]
    }
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    @available(*, unavailable) required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override public func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        switch key {
        case "inputImage":
            blurFilter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    override public var  outputImage: CIImage {
        return (blurFilter?.outputImage)! .applyingFilter("CIColorMonochrome", parameters: ["inputColor": CIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0)])
    }
}
```

If you wish to expose more attributes, you can simply add them to the `attributes` and `setValue(forKey:)` overrides along wist adding variables and `setDefaults`. Here I'm simply using the defaults.

Now that you've chained your effect together into one custom filter, you can register it and use it:

```
let CustomFilterCategory = "CustomFilter"

public class CustomFilterConstructor: NSObject, CIFilterConstructor {
    static public func registerFilter() {
        CIFilter.registerName(
            "BlurThenColor",
            constructor: CustomFilterConstructor(),
            classAttributes: [
                kCIAttributeFilterCategories: [CustomFilterCategory]
            ])
    }
    public func filter(withName name: String) -> CIFilter? {
        switch name {
        case "BlurThenColor":
            return BlurThenColor()
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

To use this, just be sure to register the filter (I tend to put mine in `AppDelegate` if possible):

```
CustomFilterConstructor.registerFilter()
```

From there, you can use `BlurThenColor` just like any other `CIFilter`. Instantiate it, use `setValue`, and call `outputImage`.

Please note, this code **will** crash because of force-unwrapping of `inputImage` and/or typos. I'm sure you can make this more safe - but rest assured that I've tested this and it works. (I created this custom filter and replaced it in an app where the force-unwraps don't happen.)

Answer (score 6):

Following the useful suggestion by dfd I ended up going with this simple subclass. I'm marking his answer correct because a) he suggested this approach and I want to give him credit, and b) it has more general use info about using `CIFilterConstructor` to register your filter.

Useful references:

- [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW1)
- [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46384693/168594)
- [Free Core Image eBook](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2016/03/core-image-for-swift-v12-released.html?view=magazine)

```
class ChainFilter: CIFilter {
  let chainedFilters: [CIFilter]
  @objc dynamic var inputImage: CIImage?

  init(_ filters: [CIFilter]) {
    self.chainedFilters = filters
    super.init()
  }

  // Run filters in order on the specified source image.
  override var outputImage: CIImage? {
    get {
      let imageKey = "inputImage"
      var workingImage = self.inputImage
      for filter in chainedFilters {
        assert(filter.inputKeys.contains(imageKey))
        filter.setValue(workingImage, forKey: imageKey)
        guard let result = filter.outputImage else {
          assertionFailure("filter failed: \(filter.name)")
          return nil
        }
        workingImage = result
      }
      return workingImage
    }
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("not implemented") }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
let myConfiguredFilters = [
  CIFilter(name: "CIMotionBlur"),
  CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert"),
  CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", parameters: ["inputRadius" : 5.0]),
]

let chainedFilters = ChainFilter(myConfiguredFilters)

let effectNode = SKEffectNode()
effectNode.filter = chainedFilters
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this class works? How would I call it on my SpriteKit node? Where do I put the filter names? How do I pass the parameters? 

My question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77767866/apply-multiple-core-image-filters-to-a-spritekit-node has been closed and I don't understand the answer accepted here.

Comment: @Ache I have updated the answer with an example of how you'd create some filters, chain them, then add them to a `SKEffectNode`. (I recall that I may have had to set `inputCenter` for some filters to get them to do what I wanted to SpriteKit and/or set `effectNode.shouldCenterFilter = true`.)

Comment: Thank you! I have managed to adapt your findings some time ago. I made it into a custom subclass that also 1) checks for the size of the output image, so it doesn't crash SpriteKit's renderer, and 2) stores the applied filters, so they are retrievable from SpriteKit. Code here: https://gist.github.com/AchrafKassioui/948173442656a26759ea0a06bdbc6fdb and SO answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77771183/prevent-spritekit-metal-renderer-from-exceeding-texture-size-limit