# Apply multiple Core Image filters to a SpriteKit node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, core-image

I can apply a Core Image filter to a SpriteKit node by:

- Making the node a child of an `SKEffectNode`
- Applying the filter to the `SKEffectNode`
- Or in the case of the scene itself, apply the filter directly, since `SKScene` inherits from `SKEffectNode`. Make sure to enable filters by setting `shouldEnableEffects = true` on the scene.

However, I can only apply one filter at a time. How do I chain filters? And how do I control the order of their application?

A similar question exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553869/on-ios-can-you-add-multiple-cifilters-to-a-spritekit-node), but I don't understand the answer. It assumes too much implicit knowledge.

Here is what I have.

The base code that sets the scene and creates a sprite node and an effect node:

```swift
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    shouldEnableEffects = true // enables filtering of the scene itself

    let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myImage")
    let myEffectNode = SKEffectNode()
    myEffectNode.addChild(mySprite)
    addChild(myEffectNode)
}
```

I can apply a Core Image filter like this:

```swift
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // previous code

    filter = CIFilter(name: "CIMotionBlur") // filters the whole scene

    myEffectNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIMotionBlur") // filters the node
}
```

But I can not chain or pile the filters like this:

```swift
myEffectNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIMotionBlur")
myEffectNode.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPixellate", parameters: [
    "inputScale": 8
])
// Only the last called filter is applied
```

How do I apply multiple filters on the same node? What are the coding patterns and structures I need to understand to do so?